# Force applied on a paramagnetic object in magnetic field

Tags: forces, magnetic-moment

I would like to determine **roughly** the force applied on a paramagnetic object (for sizing calculation). But I am not use to magnetism calculation.

Can someone confirm this expression of the force applied on the paramagnetic object :

$$\vec{F} = \iiint_V \nabla (\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B})dV$$

with $\vec{\mu}=\frac{\chi_s}{\mu}\vec{B}$

$$\vec{F} = \frac{\chi_s}{\mu}\iiint_V \nabla (\vec{B}\cdot\vec{B})dV$$

and if B is independent along $y$ and $z$ and if the volume over which one we integrate is a simple cuboid, we have

$$\vec{F}=\frac{\chi_s}{\mu} S (B(x_2)^2 - B(x_1)^2)\vec{x}$$

where $S$ is the section of the cuboid orthogonal to $\vec{x}$

Dimensional analysis says "ok" but yet...

Of course the value of B I will use for determined the force are the value I measure without anything perturbating the field, so the force I will get is only an approximation, since the presence of the parmagnetic object should modify the field. Is there any method to evaluate this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly right,  This is like a [Gouy balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouy_balance), and we happen to sell an apparatus to measure susceptibility. A news letter [here.](http://nebula.wsimg.com/da939bf87f4c7673a145df6811c54b6b?AccessKeyId=027C3581808C75E81679&disposition=0&alloworigin=1) 
(Shameless plug)  As far as I know the local field is not changed (in any measurable amount) by the presence of the paramagentic material.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice apparatus !
I was not very honest in my first post. I speak about paramagnetic object because the field is not very high (few mT) but we are going to use standard iron steel (if calculation are no good, we can go for 304 or Al) so it is not paramagnetic but ferromagnetic. That is why I mentioned a possible modification in the field, since the field line are going to concenrate in the steel. But I wonder if this effect is take into account in the susceptibility and the permeability of the material or not. Of what i know there is no such effect for few mT but again...

Comment: @Dalnor,  To do a self consistent calculation of the field, I think I like the Feynman lectures (vol 2 chaps, 35...38?) For Ferromagnetic stuff it is very complicated.